# Mutually recursive generic enums

Tags: swift, generics, enums

## Generic recursive `enum`

I can easily express a generic recursive enum in Swift:

```
indirect enum Tree<T> {
    case empty
    case leaf(T)
    case node(Tree, Tree)
}
```

Given this, I can instantiate some example trees of `Int`, say:

```
let exampleTrees: [Tree<Int>] = [
    .empty,
    .leaf(10),
    .node(.node(.leaf(1), .leaf(2)), .node(.leaf(3), .leaf(4)))
]
```

## Mutual recursion

The `Tree` enum is recursive in a similar way to a recursive function. The `empty` and `leaf` cases terminate recursion and `node` is a recursive case.

With recursive functions it is not unusual to have a pair of **mutually recursive** functions. A stupid but classic illustrative example is:

```
func isEven(_ x: Int) -> Bool {
    return x == 0 ? true : isOdd(x-1)
}

func isOdd(_ x: Int) -> Bool {
    return x == 0 ? false : isEven(x-1)
}
```

Analogously, it's also possible to declare a pair of mutually recursive `enum`s:

```
indirect enum AB {
    case a
    case b(CD)
}

indirect enum CD {
    case c
    case d(AB)
}
```

Given these, I can start creating recursive values. Here're some examples…

```
let exampleRecursives: [AB] = [
    .a,
    .b(.c),
    .b(.d(.a)),
    .b(.d(.b(.c)))
]
```

(These are obviously all completely stupid and useless – it's just to illustrate what's going on!)

## Generic mutually recursive `enum`

The definitions of `AB` and `CD` are restrictive though, because they're not generic, and I'd like them to be generic:

```
indirect enum AB<T> {
    case a
    case b(T)
}

indirect enum CD<T> {
    case c
    case d(T)
}
```

## The problem

Given that I have these generic alternatives, I'd like to be able to express the same kind of mutually recursive nesting that I could with the non generic originals. I need to tell swift that the type is `AB<CD<AB<CD<AB<CD<AB<CD<AB<CD< …`, but infinitely long.

I tried to express this as follows:

```
typealias RecursiveABCD = AB<CD<RecursiveABCD>>
```

This gives the compilation error `"Circular reference"` though.

I also tried this:

```
typealias RecursiveAB = AB<RecursiveCD>
typealias RecursiveCD = CD<RecursiveAB>
```

But again, the compiler errors with `"Circular reference"`.

## Work around

A work around would be to define a kind of wrapper, like this:

```
struct W {
    init(_ x: AB<CD<W>>) {
        self.x = x
    }

    let x: AB<CD<W>>
}
```

If I do this, I can kind of create the examples, like this:

```
let exampleRecursives: [W] = [
    W(.a),
    W(.b(.c)),
    W(.b(.d(W(.a)))),
    W(.b(.d(W(.b(.c)))))
]
```

This seems like it will become very cumbersome and awkward to use, though.

## Question

Can recursive generic enums be used without introducing a wrapper?

Comment: What is the actual issue? You can declare like `let type: AB<CD<AB<CD<String>>>>`.

Comment: @Kamran Thanks – I'll try to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: My guess is you need `typealias` to declare few easy to use types. e.g, `typealias XXX = AB<CD<AB<CD<AB<CD<String>>>>>>
`

Comment: Ah! Yes, I tried that: `typealias Rec = AB<CD<Rec>>` – but swift complains about that: "Circular reference".

Comment: What is `Rec`. You can not use same name for two types. If `Rec` is some type then you can not use this name for typealias.

Comment: `Rec` is not two types – it's the same type recursively referring to itself.